# Marketing Cloud REST API - Contact Delete operation is not currently enabled

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Tried to delete a contact in Marketing Cloud through the API

```
/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=ids

{
  "values": [
    "1131976968"
  ],
  "DeleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes"
}
```

It tells me the operation is not enabled. The only other occurence I could find after searching the forums is that someone posted that you have to ask Support to enable this. So I asked support and they told me I need to ask the forum.

```
{
  "operationInitiated": false,
  "operationID": 3,
  "requestServiceMessageID": "478343ae-33ac-4a77-a5bc-0b803cd0a84d",
  "responseDateTime": "2017-12-11T08:56:26.6365841-06:00",
  "hasErrors": true,
  "resultMessages": [
    {
        "resultType": "Operational",
        "resultClass": "Error",
        "resultCode": "OperationDisabled",
        "message": "The Contact Delete operation is not currently enabled."
    }
],
"serviceMessageID": "0ae44e81-c2f7-4322-b411-693b827abd8e"
```

Comment: Support sent you here? That’s rich. It’s not enabled by default and they would have to switch on that business rule in the back end

Comment: Yes, they closed my support ticket straight away said it was out of scope. Then I posted on developer.salesforce.com and they linked me to a post. In that post the answer said to open a case. So I tried stack instead. So..... open another support case?

Comment: Several of the Contact delete endpoints have been replaced by the [DeleteByListReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByListReference.htm) endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

This is either because

1) The delete contact business rule is not enabled on your account

2) you are making the call to the wrong business unit